# Why am I getting a LazySeq casting error?

Tags: casting, clojure

I've written the following function

```
(defn insert-block
  "Given a block, coordinate and playfield, returns the altered playfield.
   Does not check for collisions."
  [[x y] block playfield]
  (let [blocksize (count block)
    insertion (fn [a b] (vector (block a) (playfield b)))
    block-indicies (range 0 blocksize)
    field-indicies (range y (+ y blocksize))]
    (map insertion block-indicies field-indicies)))
```

Block and playfield are both vectors of vectors. For some reason, every time I call this function, I get the following error:

```
#<ClassCastException java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn>
```

The function has been simplified a bit from what's in my code - 'insertion' is more complex in the original, but I get the same error regardless. This is driving me nuts - Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: I've been testing it with [2 3] for [x y] and [[0 0 0] [0 1 0] [1 1 1]] for block. Playfield is too large to paste here, but it's a vector of 26 vectors containing integers, of length 14.

EDIT2: Here's the playfield vector.

```
[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
```

EDIT3: I've narrowed it down further - the following code works. It seems that accessing elements in the block and playfield vectors is what's causing the problem, but I still don't know why.

```
(defn insert-block
"Given a block, coordinate and playfield, returns the altered playfield.
 Does not check for collisions."
[[x y] block playfield]
(let [blocksize (count block)
  insertion (fn [a b] (vector a b))
  block-indicies (range 0 blocksize)
  field-indicies (range y (+ y blocksize))]
  (map insertion block-indicies field-indicies)))
```

Thanks

Comment: Please also show the arguments you provide to get that error. `(insert-block [1 1] [[1 2] [1 2]]  [[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [6 8 9]])` for example does not throw an exception  but I have no idea if that's expected or not. I expect you're providing a seq instead of a vector as the `block` and or `playfield` argument. Also note that your function returns a seq instead of a vector, which seems wrong if you assume that playfields are always vectors.

Comment: You're right, I should have included that. I've edited the post.

You're right about map too - that could cause problems in the future, although it seems unrelated to the issue here.

Comment: To me, it gives index out of bound exception for some of the inputs, but not the error which is pointed out.

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran What inputs were those? If y + blocksize is less than (count playfield) it shouldn't be happening.

Comment: @Joel Yes! But, that can happen, I couldn't meet your error. Can you paste your vectors..?

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran It's been added to the OP

Comment: Seems to work for me with your input. If you change the calls to (get block a) and (get playfield b), do you get a different exception?

Comment: @AdrianMouat That seems to have done the trick, though I'm not sure why (what's the difference between (get vector num) and (vector num)?). If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Your original code works with the input you provided. I'm pretty much convinced you're not really passing those inputs to the function in the real code. Very very likely your actual args are seqs and not vectors.

Comment: @Joel there's no real difference, but you would have a got a different exception. I suspect it was just that something was defined differently in your repl.

Comment: (I won't post an answer as I don't think it would be useful to be anyone)

Comment: @JoostDiepenmaat Interesting - I'm calling the function directly from the REPL to test it, but the vectors I'm calling it with were defined in a clj file I loaded. Is the behaviour of the language different between files and the REPL?

Comment: @Joel - it shouldn't matter where the input is coming from. If you put all the code in files or on the REPL the output should be the same. But to get to the bottom of a problem like this, it's generally a very good idea to have a simple, self-contained source file - code and actual literal input data - that demonstrates the problem in the first place (and that you can copy/paste here if you can't figure out what's wrong). For now, the code you've posted here just doesn't exhibit the problem you're describing.

Comment: @Joel - if you query the data in the REPL, you should be able to see whether they're actually vectors or seqs; seqs print with parentheses "(....)", while vectors print with square brackets "[....]". Your code will only work with vectors as arguments and will throw the described exception if you provide one or more (lazy) seqs instead.

Comment: @JoostDiepenmaat Well, I feel stupid now - Playfield actually was a sequence of vectors. Thanks for making me take a closer look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're not really passing vectors to your function. It works for the vectors you supplied, using clojure 1.3.

A safer way to retrieve the nth value from a collection in clojure is the [nth](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/nth) function. This function will work for whatever type of collection you pass in, lists, vectors, sequences and more.

As Joost commented, your function returns a lazy sequence, which might not be what you want. If you absolutely need a vector back you could pass the result of map to [vec](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/vec).

Comment: Just noticed that the OP figured it out via the comments by Joost by the time I finished my answer. Should I delete this answer, or is it still useful?

Comment: I'd leave the answer, better than having it on the unanswered list

Comment: It makes it more obvious for anyone reading this in the future - I'd leave it.